# Discord.js crypto currency command returning undefined for prices

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I created a command to get the price data of a given cryptocurrency. When I run my command, the embed has "undefined" for each price value.

Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'crypto',
    description: 'gets crypto data',
    async execute (message, args) {

        let cc = args.slice(0).join(' ');

        const noArgs = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Missing arguments')
        .setColor((Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16).padStart(6, '0'))
        .setDescription('You are missing some args (ex: -crypto bitcoin || -covid dogecoin)')
        .setTimestamp(new Date().getTime())
    
        if(!cc) return message.channel.send(noArgs);

        await fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${cc}&vs_currencies=usd%2Ceur%2Cgbp`)
        .then (response => response.json)
        .then(data => {
            let usdprice = data.usd
            let europrice = data.eur
            let gbpprice = data.gbp

            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**Current price of ${cc}:**`)
            .setDescription('This data might be inaccurate.')
            .setColor((Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16).padStart(6, '0'))
            .setTimestamp(new Date().getTime())
            .addField('**USD:**', usdprice, true)
            .addField('**EURO:**', europrice, true)
            .addField('**GBP:**', gbpprice, true)

            message.channel.send(embed)
        })
        
    }
}
```

There is also no error in the console when I run the command.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `cc` and the returned `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async/await if you've already got an async `execute` function. this way you can get rid of the `then()`s.

One of the problem is what @Mellet mentioned, you need to call `response.json()`.

The other one is that the fetch data looks like this (if the coin id is "bitcoin"):

```json
{
  "bitcoin": {
    "usd": 44833,
    "eur": 36948,
    "gbp": 32383
  }
}
```

It means that it returns an object which contains another object with the coin id as the key. So if `cc`'s value is `bitcoin`, you can get the USD price from `data.bitcoin.usd`. You can't and don't want to hardcode the coin id though, so you will need to add the key as a variable: `data[coinId].usd`.

I also added a helper function to check if the returned data is empty, so you can send an error message:

```js
const isEmptyObject = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).length === 0;

module.exports = {
  name: 'crypto',
  description: 'gets crypto data',
  async execute(message, args) {
    let cc = args.slice(0).join(' ');

    if (!cc) {
      const noArgs = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Missing arguments')
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setDescription(
          'You are missing some args (ex: -crypto bitcoin || -covid dogecoin)',
        )
        .setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());

      return message.channel.send(noArgs);
    }

    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${cc}&vs_currencies=usd%2Ceur%2Cgbp`
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    if (isEmptyObject(data)) {
      return message.channel.send(
        `No returned data from the API. Are you sure "${cc}" is a valid id?`,
      );
    }

    let usdprice = data[cc].usd;
    let europrice = data[cc].eur;
    let gbpprice = data[cc].gbp;

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`**Current price of ${cc}:**`)
      .setDescription('This data might be inaccurate.')
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setTimestamp(new Date().getTime())
      .addField('**USD:**', usdprice, true)
      .addField('**EURO:**', europrice, true)
      .addField('**GBP:**', gbpprice, true);

    message.channel.send(embed);
  },
};
```

PS: You can [set the colour to `'RANDOM'`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ColorResolvable), so you don't need to use extra functions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.then (response => response.json)
```

Should be

```
.then (response => response.json())
```